# Resuming jquery cycle with a delay

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I am trying to resume a Jquery cycle plugin slideshow, but only after a delay of X miliseconds. The set up is for the slideshow to play while being hovered over, and to pause while not (while other content is scrolled on top of it essentially) The following code is not registering a delay before it resumes

Any help much appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// configure the cycle plugin
$('.slideshowtwo').cycle({
     fx:     'scrollUp',
     speed:   1000,
     timeout: 1200,
     pause:   0
});
$('.slideshowtwo').cycle('pause'); // pause it right away.

$('.slideshowtwo').hover(
    function() {
            $(this).delay(5000).cycle('resume'); // start playing after delay
    },
    function(){
        $(this).cycle('pause'); // pause the slideshow.
    }
).trigger('hover');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code you want to run after a delay in a setTimeout function. I've now edited your code to wrap the pause into the setTimeout as well. Also, I've stored the slideshowtwo class into a variable so you don't call the selector so often. This should improve performance. However, if the class is being removed and added to elements for whatever reason, you should go back to dynamically searching for it. The code below should suit you just fine though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// configure the cycle plugin
var showTwo = $('.slideshowtwo');
showTwo.cycle({
     fx:     'scrollUp',
     speed:   1000,
     timeout: 1200,
     pause:   0
});
showTwo.cycle('pause'); // pause it right away.

showTwo.hover(
    setTimeout(function(){
        function() {
                showTwo.cycle('resume'); // start playing after delay
        },
        function(){
            showTwo.cycle('pause'); // pause the slideshow.
        }
    }, 5000)
).trigger('hover');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing it to this breaks the pausing function but I liked the idea!

Comment: Move the pause function into the body of the setTimeout function as well.